# custom logging to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging

I am trying to store custom logging error in database, so i have

```
 public enum Events
{
    Error,
    Info,
    Debug
}    

public class Logging
{
    public int LoggingID { get; set; }
    public Events EventName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

and for each event I made a message like this example

```
 LogHelper.Infos(" Running application ");
        ConfigureAuth(app);
```

How can I store those events in database?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Log entity something like this:

```
public class LogAction
{
        public DateTime PerformedAt { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a custom attribute like this:

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IUnitOfWork Uow { get; set; }
        public ILogActionService LogActionService { get; set; }

        public IApplicationUserManager ApplicationUserManager { get; set; }
        public LogAttribute(string desciption)
        {
            Description = desciption;
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            string currentUserId = null;
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                currentUserId = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }
            var model = new LogAction
            {
                UserName = currentUserId ?? "Anonymouse user",
                Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
                Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                Description = Description,
                PerformedAt = DateTime.Now,
                Ip = Helper.Helper.GetUser_IP_Message()
            };
            LogActionService.AddLog(model);
            Uow.SaveAllChanges();
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, in the `OnActionExecuted` method you can populate the entity and save it to database, So you can use the attribute this way:

```
[Log("Home Page")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```